# Frequency Limitation in robot_localization's EKF Node

Tags: imu, localization, robot-localization, ekf

I'm using version 2.7.4 of the robot_localization package for ROS Noetic.

I'm currently utilizing two nodes of the package:

- EKF Local Node: Fuses data from an IMU (100Hz) and wheel encoders (4Hz).
- EKF Global Node: Fuses the output of the EKF Local Node with GPS data (4Hz).

Despite these frequencies, the ekf_global node's frequency appears bounded between 60-65 Hz (asking for 100). And the ekf_local node's frequency appears bounded between 80-85 Hz(asking for 100). This restriction remains even when altering the input frequencies. with a lot of "Failed to meet update rate! Took 0.02000X" warnings in the console.

**Configuration:**

*launch file:*

```
        <launch>
            <arg name="namespace" default="fjcruiser" />
            <arg name="base_link_frame" value="$(arg namespace)/base_footprint" />
            <arg name="use_legacy_odom" default="false" />

            <!-- Load conf and parameters from yaml files -->
            <rosparam command="load" file="$(find ugv_odometry)/config/origins.yaml"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find ugv_odometry)/params/$(arg namespace)/localization.yaml" />

            <!-- Set the origin as a rosparam -->
            <node pkg="ugv_odometry" type="initializer_node" name="initializer_node" output="screen" />
            <!-- GNSS velocity converter-->
            <node name="gnss_velocity_converter" pkg="ugv_odometry" type="gnss_velocity_converter" output="screen" />
            
            <!-- EKF LOCAL-->
            <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_local" respawn="false" output="screen">
                <rosparam command="load" file="$(find ugv_odometry)/config/$(arg namespace)/ekf_local.yaml"/>
                <param name="base_link_frame" value="$(arg base_link_frame)"/>
                <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="relative_odom"/>
            </node>

            <!-- EKF Global -->
            <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_global" respawn="true" output="screen">
                <rosparam command="load" file="$(find ugv_odometry)/config/common/ekf_global.yaml"/>
            <param name="base_link_frame" value="$(arg base_link_frame)" />
                <param name="odom0" value="/$(arg namespace)/relative_odom" />
            <param name="odom1" value="/$(arg namespace)/navsat/odometry" />
                <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odom" />
            </node>

            <!-- Navsat Transform Node -->
            <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true">
                <rosparam command="load" file="$(find ugv_odometry)/config/common/navsat_transform.yaml"/>
                <remap from="imu/data" to="imu" />
                <remap from="gps/fix" to="fix" />
                <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odom" />
                <remap from="odometry/gps" to="navsat/odometry" />
            </node>
         <launch>
```

*ekf_local.yaml*

```
frequency: 100
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
world_frame: odom
odom_frame: odom
debug: false
debug_out_file: /home/developer/workspace/rosbag/ekf_local_debug_file
reset_on_time_jump: true
publish_tf: true
dynamic_process_noise_covariance: true
#transform_time_offset: 0.05

# -------------------------------------
# IMU configuration:
# -------------------------------------

imu0: /fjcruiser/imu
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false,  false,  false,
                false, false, false,
                false, false, true,
                false, false, false]
imu0_differential: false
imu0_queue_size: 50 
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
imu0_nodelay: true
# -------------------------------------
# GNSS Doppler velocity configuration:
# -------------------------------------

odom0: /fjcruiser/converted_gnss_velocity
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                       false, false, false,
                       true, true, false,
                       false, false, false,
                       false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false
odom0_queue_size: 4
odom0_nodelay: true

# [ADVANCED] This matrix represents the noise we add to the total error after each prediction step.

process_noise_covariance: [0.005, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0.005, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0.006, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.03,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,    0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02,  0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01,  0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01,  0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]

# [ADVANCED] This represents the initial value for the state estimate error covariance matrix.

initial_estimate_covariance: [0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

*ekf_global.yaml*

```
# The frequency of the output
frequency: 50
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
debug: false
debug_out_file: /home/developer/workspace/rosbag/ekf_global_debug_file
reset_on_time_jump: true
publish_tf: true
dynamic_process_noise_covariance: true
#transform_time_offset: 0.05

# The frame IDs
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
world_frame: map

# Sensor configurations
# Local EKF odometry settings
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false
odom0_queue_size: 50
odom0_nodelay: true

# GNSS settings
odom1_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
odom1_differential: false
odom1_queue_size: 4
odom1_nodelay: true

# [ADVANCED] This matrix represents the noise we add to the total error after each prediction step.

process_noise_covariance: [0.005, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0.005, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0.006, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]

# [ADVANCED] This represents the initial value for the state estimate error covariance matrix.

initial_estimate_covariance: [1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

As requested you will find below a sample message from each sensor input:

**Fix**

```
header: 
  seq: 4502
  stamp: 
    secs: 1691504843
    nsecs: 100990753
  frame_id: "fjcruiser/gnss1_antenna_wgs84"
status: 
  status: 0
  service: 1
latitude: 24.4363592
longitude: 54.6110056
altitude: -19.088
position_covariance: [0.4342809729757313, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4342809729757313, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7259039967498779]
position_covariance_type: 2
```

**imu**

```
header: 
  seq: 136324
  stamp: 
    secs: 1691505083
    nsecs:  75626252
  frame_id: "fjcruiser/sensor_wgs84"
orientation: 
  x: -0.42456197949594277
  y: 0.9053296474668617
  z: -0.004811025879026105
  w: -0.010112218289144895
orientation_covariance: [1.2389542403262732e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2375152844005589e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5143168398652242e-05]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.00975768268108368
  y: 0.01087676640599966
  z: 0.0530206598341465
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.7374916076660156
  y: 0.49138200283050537
  z: -10.263421058654785
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
```

**Wheel_encoder:**

```
header: 
  seq: 62
  stamp: 
    secs: 1691504859
    nsecs: 601004771
  frame_id: "fjcruiser/base_footprint"
child_frame_id: "fjcruiser/base_footprint"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.00014493087447644442
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

And as requested this is my TF launch file:

```
    <launch>
        <arg name="namespace" default="" />
        <arg name="robot_tf_prefix" default="$(arg namespace)/"/>
        <arg name="type" default="$(arg type)/" /> <!-- real, simulation or rosbag-->
    
        <group if="$(eval arg('namespace') == 'sbuggy')"> 
    
            <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="$(arg namespace)_link_broadcaster" args="0.375 0 2.29 0 0 0 $(arg namespace)/base_footprint $(arg namespace)/base_link" />  
            <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="$(arg namespace)_linkcenter_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 $(arg namespace)/base_footprint $(arg namespace)/center_link" /> 
            <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="$(arg namespace)_link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 $(arg namespace)/base_link $(arg namespace)/os1/os_sensor" /> 
            <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="$(arg namespace)_link2_broadcaster" args="1.10 -0.48 -0.71 0.01151917 0.02600541 0.02600541 $(arg namespace)/base_link $(arg namespace)/os2/os_sensor" /> 
            <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="$(arg namespace)_link3_broadcaster" args="1.10 0.56 -0.71 0.02722714 0.02234021 0.04258603 $(arg namespace)/base_link $(arg namespace)/os3/os_sensor" />
            <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="$(arg namespace)_link4_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 $(arg namespace)/base_link $(arg namespace)/gnss1_antenna_wgs84" />
            <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="$(arg namespace)_link5_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 3.14 0 $(arg namespace)/base_link $(arg namespace)/sensor_wgs84" />
      </group>
</launch>
```

**Observations and Testing:**

- CPU Load: Always remains below 10% across all cores.
- EKF local Frequency: The limiting frequency of around 80/85 hz remains consistent, even when input frequencies are varied.
- Compilation and Debugging: The package is compiled in release mode, and the debug parameter is set to false.
- Input Queue Sizes: Altering the sizes doesn't have a discernable impact on frequency.
- EKF Dependency: The frequency of ekf_global always matches the maximum frequency of ekf_local. If I set the ekf_local to 10 Hz, I will have also 10Hz on the ekf_global regardless of the asked frequency.
- TF Frequency: The frequency of the /tf topic is the combined frequency of the odom and relative_odom topics.
- TF Interactions: Both EKF nodes have interdependent TF requirements. However, when I replaced the TF produced by ekf_global with a static TF, there was no improvement on frequency.

**Request:**
I'm keen on understanding the reasons behind the frequency limitation of the ekf_local nodes and any potential solutions or workarounds that can be recommended.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I do apologise for the massive delay in looking at this. I don't get a lot of time to do support for `r_l` these days.

However, I have good news for you.

For background, as with many systems, the time stamps that are coming in from your various data sources are not always consistent. In your case, this is happening:

- In cycle 1, the EKF receives an IMU measurement with timestamp 10
- The EKF does its fusion, and outputs a message with timestamp 10
- In cycle 2, it receives a velocity measurement with timestamp < 10
- This forces the EKF to do a correction in which it rewinds the state, inserts your new measurement, then fuses them all again
- What you might expect now is that the EKF publishes its output again here (note it would publish with timestamp 10 again).

This is where things get tricky. By default, the EKF will *not* publish these "corrected" states. The reason for this is that if `tf2` receives a transform at a time stamp for which it already has a transform, it will spit out a warning. The reason it warns you is that that information is ignored by `tf2` internally; it doesn't support *updating* transforms in the transform tree. There was a long discussion about this [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/467), but the short version is that we added a flag to `r_l` to prevent it publishing messages with duplicate transforms.

So what's happening is that for most of your cycles, your measurements are coming in in order, but once in a while, one of the EKF update cycles gets an out-of-order measurement, and so it does its rewind and fusion, but *does not publish*.

It also explains why your second EKF instance is even slower: the additional measurement source might also be generating old messages, so even more of your update cycles are ignored.

Fortunately for you, there are two fixes:

1. Fix the nodes generating your IMU and odometry measurements so that they publish very accurate time stamps, and they publish as soon as possible after obtaining their data.
2. If you really just need the output frequency to be correct, add this to your EKF config:

```
permit_corrected_publication: true
```

When I changed this parameter, I got the correct output frequencies.

```
$ rostopic hz /fjcruiser/odom 
subscribed to [/fjcruiser/odom]
WARNING: may be using simulated time
average rate: 100.295
    min: 0.000s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.01685s window: 100
```

---

Original response:

I would ask that you please edit your question and add a sample message from each sensor input. In the meantime, I would recommend two things:

1. You should not fuse the output of the `odom` frame EKF into the `map` frame instance. Instead, just fuse the same sensor inputs in both instances, but add the GPS data to the second instance. This won't have any bearing on your `odom` frame EKF instance output rate, but the current setup will create an artificial lag in your `map` frame state estimate.
2. I am not clear on why the `odom` frame instance would output at only 85 Hz. I've fused data from multiple IMUs running at 100 Hz without the node breaking a sweat. Off the top of my head, one thing I would recommend strongly is that you make sure the timestamps on all the sensor inputs are absolutely correct. If they aren't, then you can get into this situation:

- Over 25 cycles, we process 25 IMU measurements
- We received one wheel encoder message with a timestamp that is delayed by 0.3 seconds.
- The filter now has to look up the last posterior state that preceded that measurement, insert it, and then re-fuse all the IMU messages from that time until the current time.

Have you tried *just* fusing the IMU data? Obviously that won't work for a state estimate, and the covariance will explode rapidly, but it would be interesting to see if the output frequency behaves better.

The output rate of the `map` frame instance being tied to the output rate of the `odom` frame instance makes sense, as we have to look up the `odom->base_link` transform in the `map` frame instance before we can publish `map->odom`. [That lookup has a timeout parameter](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/5cf7feb4cc0181fb5153f79fe2df0f91e299c343/src/ros_filter_utilities.cpp#L111-L112) (you have it set to 0.1), and so the node will block until that transform is available for the time in question.

EDIT after requested information was provided:

- The fact that the frequency increased when you changed the sensor timeout tells me this is likely to do with your input data. But that is definitely the wrong way to do this. You're forcing the EKF to do an update when there should be no need to.
- Let's focus on your "local" EKF instance first. You specify the `world_frame` to be `odom`, but you have *no* parameter for the `base_link_frame`. That means it will default to `base_link`. The velocity in your wheel encoder data (which you are trying to fuse in the EKF) is given in the `fjcruiser/base_footprint` frame. As noted in the `r_l` documentation, you need to provide a transform from `base_link` to `fjcruiser/base_footprint`. Where is that transform being provided? Are you using a static transform publisher? If so, can you provide the launch config you are using? Or are you perhaps using a URDF that defines those transforms?
- Same goes for your IMU data. You gave it a `frame_id` of `fjcruiser/sensor_wgs84`, but you are asking it to fuse angular Z velocity from the IMU, and I don't see a transform provided from `base_link` to `fjcruiser/sensor_wgs84`.

Comment: 1. Agree I will update this

2. First I noticed that modifying the property sensor_timeout to 0.0005 help reduce the issue, now I'm able now to get 97 Hz when asking for 100 but still I'm facing a lot of "Failed to meet update rate!" warnings. But no warnings when only 80 Hz is requested.
I did the test that you have suggested (having only IMU as input and disabling ekf_global) and it's the same thing, reaching a max of 97Hz with a lot of warnings

Comment: Sorry forgot about that, just edited my post to include my tf launch file

Comment: Do you have a bag file?

Comment: Yes here:
https://tiiuae-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/ayoub_asri_tii_ae/El3rJ4aOR6xPlRQGodoCZ-kBkhr3e-4okly3YZAm393JeA?e=zQGL63

Comment: In this bagfile there is no wheel encoders, I use instead GNSS Doppler velocity after converting it to vehicule frame.
Anyway, from my side just running the ekf_local with only IMU data at 100 hz gives me a lot of "Failed to meet update rate!"
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @user2454945 can you please assemble an isolated set of launch files to go with this bag file? Yours point to local workspaces, are missing the navsat transform config, etc. I really don't have the cycles to try to correct all of that. If you can put together everything I need to be able to see it without having to get the launch files massaged, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Hello,
Sorry for the late answer.
You will find below a bag file with all the required resources.
Dont forget the use_sim_time and --clock in rosbag play.
thank you

https://tiiuae-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/ayoub_asri_tii_ae/El3rJ4aOR6xPlRQGodoCZ-kBkhr3e-4okly3YZAm393JeA?e=yA35cT

Comment: have you had the time to run the bagfiles? @automatom

Comment: Apologies, not yet. Full time job that doesn't use this package, life, etc. This package is also being deprecated soon. Will try to find time at some point.

Comment: Oh, one other thing: when you use the fix I mentioned above, you should get rid of the `sensor_timeout`

Comment: @user2454945 sorry for the ping after my long-delayed response, but can you confirm the fix above works for you? If so, can you accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @automatom
Sorry for the late answer, I have just tested your fix.
For some reason when I enable permit_corrected_publication in ekf_global.yaml, I face a contunious TF_REPEATED_DATA warnings, whether sensor_timeout is commented or not.


Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame mbuggy/odom (parent mbuggy/map) at time 1705222454.527242 according to authority unknown_publisher
         at line 278 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-tf2-0.7.7/src/buffer_core.cpp

Comment: Yes, that's why the `permit_corrected_publication` parameter was added at all:

https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/467

Your options are to fix your data so it arrives strictly in order or live with the lower frequency. The core issue is that you have old messages arriving after newer ones.